# Accommodate vs accommodate for

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, difference

I think I have read "accommodate for" in many places (and it actually has [millions of hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22accommodate+for%22)), but I am having trouble finding if it really is a correct or recommended expression or not. Looking at [the definition of "acommodate" from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accommodate) does not mention it, and it provides an example for what I thought "accommodate for" was used for:

> **4** **:** to give consideration to **:** to allow for
>   // trying to *accommodate* the special interests of various groups

Is "accommodate for" correct? If it is, can I always use "accommodate" in its place? And is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: There are many contexts where *to **accommodate** X* (no preposition) can be directly replaced by *to **allow for** X*. That's probably what leads some non-native speakers to include the preposition with the first verb, but it's not something native speakers would often do.